# Ajax is switching the contents of the Data variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, .htaccess

I contacted the tech support about a problem with Ajax where Ajax wouldn't execute due to Access-Control-Allow-Origin problems. He fixed the issue be adding a file called .htaccess containing the code `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` . I'm saying this because I'm not entirely sure if it's relevant. The issue is that Ajax is switching the value of the Data variable from the input contents to copying the entire script and using that as the value. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening or how but after debugging a bit it seems that this is happening only within Ajax. I checked and JavaScript is correctly taking the value of the input but as it is passed through Ajax the value of the `form_data` variable is replaced with a copy of the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready(function() {

$("#my_form").submit(function(event){
    //alert ("submited");

    event.preventDefault("#my_form");

    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission
    //var form_data = $('#submit_post').val(),

    alert (post_url + "" + request_method + " " + form_data);

    $.ajax({
        type: request_method,
        url: post_url,
        data: form_data,
        //crossDomain: true,
        success: function( html ) {
            alert (html);
            $('#server-results').html(html);
        },
    });
 });
});
```

And here is the screen shot of `alert (html);`

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Sorry if the image isn't displaying, the link doesn't seem to connect when I click on it. Just imagine an alert showing a copy of the code my page is running

Comment: `event.preventDefault("#my_form");` is wrong.... You do not include a form name....

Comment: My guess is the post_url is wrong.....

Comment: @epascarello it's just a precaution method, besides it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @epascarello, You mean form_data?

Comment: No.... `post_url` and preventDefault does not accept any parameters so it does nothing,.... I was just pointing out that it did nothing. What is the basic form tag look like?

Comment: So what does the form tag look like?

Comment: what do you mean? The form ID is #my_form

Comment: `<form  id="my_form" ..... >` replace urls with example.com if you do not want us to know where you are submitting it to.

Comment: well? You going to post it?

Comment: "as it is passed through Ajax the value of the form_data variable is replaced with a copy of the script." No that's not what's happening. An ajax call doesn't just return the same data to you. It can process that data and return something else. Your alert is showing whatever the server chooses to return, it is not showing what you sent to the server. They are totally unrelated. If you want to see what actually got _sent_ to the server, check the network tab in your browser and look at the request body for the ajax request.

Comment: As for what is being returned, we can't see the server-side script so maybe that's what it's meant to return. Looks like it just returns a whole HTML page, which suggests it's intended to be used via a normal postback, and therefore return a new page to the browser. If it was intended to be used via ajax it would likely return a snippet of HTML that you could insert into your page somewhere, or some data as XML or JSON which your script could read and process as needed. I think you're trying to use a script for a purpose it was not meant for.

Comment: And BTW using * with Access-Control-Allow-Origin is generally not clever from a security perspective. Anyone can now write CORS requests to that script from any domain. That may not be a problem in your case, but usually good practice, unless it's a universal public API, is to restrict it to a specific domain or domains

Comment: Any ideas how I could fix it without *? Ajax won't even run without it and I want to make my website a public service eventually

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out guys, the link in the form was the webpage itself! It was originally a second webpage but I changed it to send to itself to see what would happen when I was debugging it and forgot to change it back! For some reason that made ajax output the script of the webpage